# vb.net Writing & Reading Multiline Text in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, text, multiline

I'm trying to create a messaging system e.g. I have a table in a MySQL database called tbluser which holds the data for every user. One record is one user which has the field of 'StatusMessage'. This field can have values which can be written onto multiple lines, but I am having trouble on how to separate the text this field holds into multiple lines using a ListBox.

```vb
Private Sub lstMessages_VisibleChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstMessages.VisibleChanged
    Dim Query As String = "SELECT StatusMessage FROM tbluser WHERE UserID=@userID"

    Using Conn As New MySqlConnection(MySQL.ConnectionDetails)
        Using Comm As New MySqlCommand()
            With Comm
                .Connection = Conn
                .CommandText = Query
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", CInt(cboSelectUser.SelectedItem.ToString))
            End With
            Try
                Conn.Open()
                Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader = Comm.ExecuteReader
                lstMessages.Items.Clear()
                While Reader.Read OrElse (Reader.NextResult And Reader.Read)
                    lstMessages.Items.Add(Reader.GetString(0))
                End While
            Catch ex As MySqlException

            End Try
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

At the moment, all the text appears onto one line.

Also, another question, how would I insert text into the database with multiple lines.

Comment: so someone is entering text with, say, a comma at he end of a line and you want a listbox to separate them where a line may have a comma at the end? That would look rather odd. Note, I threw in the comma at the end perhaps as an extreme and not your case

Comment: The split function would split the line at a specific character. Which you could then write to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, what I ended up doing was changing the component used into a RichTextBox. Also, I changed every instance of the string "\n" which is a new line in MySQL to Environment.NewLine().

To insert new messages into the field, I had to select all of the text already in the field and then add to that text so I used a combination of a SELECT query and UPDATE query along with Environment.NewLine() so I can write to new lines.